# Cannot find emcc - emscripten

Tags: git-bash, emscripten, emcc, emsdk

I'm trying to execute a .bat and i get:

```
Building demos/touchscreen...
Cannot find emcc
        Emscripten is not installed (or not in your PATH)
```

I found the "emcc" file and it is located here: C:\emsdk\emscripten\1.38.23
So I checked the system environment variables and edited "path" variable adding as a value the location "C:\emsdk\emscripten\1.38.23"
It still cant find the emcc. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Did you restart git-bash after updating the path variable?

Comment: yes i did and nothing changed

Comment: Ok I did it but... now it says 'libmbed.bc does not exist. Building...
Mbed CLI (mbed) is not installed'

Comment: Did you refer the issue https://github.com/janjongboom/mbed-simulator/issues/32?

Comment: Set the variable EMSDK to the folder, where emsdk.bat is inside. Then set this path variable, maybe?
set PATH=%EMSDK%;%EMSDK%\upstream\emscripten;%PATH%